# Using git smudge and clean filters, and textconv to version control binary files

Tags: git, binary, diff

I would like to use Git to version control some binary files, but it would be nice to have some meaningful diffs for those. The file format is propietary so I can't extract information from them, but I can produce a separate text file with meaningful information of the binary.

I know that you can tell Git to diff binary files using *textconv*, and I've learnt about smudge and clean filters.

My question is: Could I use smudge and clean filters to insert a meaningful text into the binary files (e.g. at the beginning of the file) and *textconv* to diff those files? Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Note that textconv filter works on a file that went through clean filter, so assuming clean filter leaves only binary part, text part would not be there to output for diff